# Times New Roman font in Jasper Report 4.7

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

## Overview

A report uses Times New Roman. I installed the font through iReport's `Tools -> Options -> Fonts` menu. I exported the font as an extension (jar file) and added it to the application's CLASSPATH.

## Problem

When exporting to PDF, the text of field has been cut from the end. The generated PDF has the Times New roman font listed in the PDF properties, indicating that the font is embedded.

I guess this is a font problem or incompatibility issue with JasperReport 4.7 because I changed the font type to Verdana and the PDF generated correctly.

The Times New Roman is used in iReport and in the extension file was copied from Windows.

## Questions

Is there some version of Times New Roman that works perfectly with the JasperReport library?

Should I not use the Times new Roman?

## Update

I attached two image with the screen shots of reports.

The first image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr7XD.jpg illustrates the correct printing of the report. I highlight the word "anexo" with a red line. This word has been cut when using the times new roman font.

The second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdW63.jpg illustrates the report generated with the times new roman font. Notice, the word "anexo" wasn't printed. The red line shows that the field was printed until word "localização"

PS1: The two attached files show parts of a report in the portuguese language

PS2: The black rectangles hide sensitive data. Don't take them account

Answer (score 4):

Try to bundle the following set of common used fonts:

Their JAR file bundles the following fonts,

```
Arial
Times New Roman
Courier New
Comic Sans MS
Georgia
Verdana
Monospaced
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ar.com.fdvs/DynamicJasper-core-fonts/1.0

Comment: I exported the fonts extension from the iReport as described at question description.